# Немогу решить задание без использование min max

Tags: c++

[image: 17-тое задание не могу решить, преподаватель говорит min max использовать нельзя.]

17-тое задание не могу решить, преподаватель говорит min max использовать нельзя.

Comment: Напишите свой. Или просто используйте тернарный оператор.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Я конечно только начал изучать C++, но допустим, что так:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int
main ()
{
  int x, y, z;
  cin >> x;
  cin >> y;
  cin >> z;
  int max_up;
  if (x + z > z * y)
    {
      max_up = x + z;
    }
  else
    {
      max_up = x * y;
    }
  int up;
  up = x + max_up;

  int min_down;
  if (x > y)
    {
      min_down = x;
    }
  else
    {
      min_down = y;
    }
  int down;
  down = min_down + x * x;

  int f;
  f = up / down;
  cout << f;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: У вас все хорошо, кроме типов данных и ,соответственно , деления